# Why does string comparison not work as expected

Tags: c, fgets, strcmp

I'm (finding the area of a TRIANGLE or a SQUARE or a CIRCLE, value is based on user input) that I made. There isn't any error, but I think the function's placement is incorrect. Whenever I type the SHAPE that I want to find, it just immediately went to the ELSE statement ("OTHER SHAPE NOT AVAILABLE"). Can you guys help show me what is wrong?

````
#define pi 3.14

int areaTriangle (int valueBase, int valueHeight);
int areaSquare (int valueSide);
int areaCircle (int valueRadius);

int main() {
 
    // program
    while (1) {

        char shape[20];

        printf("what geometry shape do you want to find? (TRIANGLE/SQUARE/CIRCLE) =");
        fgets(shape, 20, stdin);

        if ( strcmp(shape, "TRIANGLE") == 0) {
            int height;
            int base;

            printf("height = ");
            scanf("%d", &height);
            printf("base = ");
            scanf("%d", &base);

            // INPUT TRIANGLE AREA FUNCTION
            areaTriangle (height, base);
        }

        else if ( strcmp(shape, "SQUARE") == 0) {
            int side;

            printf("side = ");
            scanf("%d", &side);
        
            // INPUT SQUARE AREA FUNCTION
            areaSquare (side);
        }

        else if ( strcmp(shape, "CIRCLE") == 0) {
            int radius;

            printf("radius = ");
            scanf("%d", &radius);
        
            // INPUT CIRCLE AREA FUNCTION
            areaCircle (radius);
        }

        else
            printf("OTHER SHAPE NOT AVAILABLE\n");

    }
    return 0;
}

int areaTriangle (int valueBase, int valueHeight) {
    int area = (valueBase*valueHeight) / 2;

    return printf("The area of this triangle is = %d", area);
}

int areaSquare (int valueSide) {
    int area = valueSide * valueSide;

    return printf("The area of this square is = %d", area);
}

int areaCircle (int valueRadius){
    int area = pi * valueRadius * valueRadius;

    return printf("The area of this circle is = %d", area);
}
```
````

Comment: After `fgets`, the last character in `shape` will most likely be `\n`.  If the input was too long so that `\n` is not the last character, then it doesn't match.  If the input was short enought that it does contain `\n`, then it doesn't match.

Comment: Thankyou! But the last problems appeared. Whenever the result of the area (let's say triangle area) printed, it will always be followed by (*the question asking the shape* = OTHER SHAPE NOT AVAILABLE) --> this part isn't intended. And after that the while-loop loop again (this part is intended)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [the `fgets` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) can retain the newline in the buffer it writes.

Either you need to update your comparisons to also include the newline:

```
strcmp(shape, "TRIANGLE\n")
```

Or remove the newline before using the string:

```
while (fgets(shape, 20, stdin) != NULL)
{
    // Replace the newline with the string terminator
    shape[strcspn(shape, "\n")] = '\0';

    if (strcmp(shape, "TRIANGLE") == 0) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: or use srtncmp (shape, "TRIANGLE", 8) (https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/), just in case there is input after the shape name

Comment: Thankyou! But the last problems appeared. Whenever the result of the area (let's say triangle area) printed, it will always be followed by (*the question asking the shape* = OTHER SHAPE NOT AVAILABLE) --> this part isn't intended. And after that the while-loop loop again (this part is intended)

Comment: @imnotarobot That's because you mix `fgets` with `scanf`. The `scanf` calls will *not* read the newline, leaving it for the `fgets` call to read the first thing it does. And then `fgets` will think it's an empty line. Use `fgets` for *all* you input, and then use e.g. `sscanf` to parse the input (but for these inputs you don't need to remove the newline).